# WordPress Nextend Social Login plugin Facebook login - App verification

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins

On our WordPress site, we needed to have Facebook login functionality.

For that reason, we installed the Nextend Social plugin and configured our app inside the Facebook developer dashboard.

[image]

---

[image]

Everything works as expected but we noticed that Facebook has App verification for Business and Individual verification.

We also noticed when we switch our Application inside the Facebook developer dashboard to Live mode everything works as expected without a problem.

So our question is: Do we need to verify our App in order just to use Facebook login functionality where we only need email and user's name?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: If you are not asking for any permissions that require review, then you probably won’t have to.

Comment: Thank you for your response I think I figured it out. It looks like that Facebook doesn't need to review your app if you are using only public_profile and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and for anyone that is asking the same question the answer is:

If you only need public_profile and email data then you do not need to submit you App to the review, as per the Facebook App review page:

[image]

Digging into Nextend Social WordPress plugin I figured out that they only ask for:

`protected $scopes = array(
    'public_profile',
    'email'
);`